# Collaborative filtering with limited item sets

Tags: recommender-system

I want to build a recommender system with collaborative filtering. The number of users in my data sets is about 3 million, however, the **number of items** users can buy **is limited to 20.**

There is no rating information only whether a user bought an item or not.
Does anyone know whether the limited number of items is a problem to use collaborative filtering?

Comment: I don't **know** but I don't see why it would be a problem :) On the contrary, I would think that the less, the better.

Comment: You should try to figure out how your items related to each other instead of studying your users. Item based collaborative filtering might be a good starting point for you, you do not have any limit on the number of items